# iOS 11 Drag and Drop: Customize Drag Count Badge

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, ios11, xcode9-beta

I am trying to customize the drag and drop count badge in the upper right hand corner of the preview image.  It currently can show a blue number, green + number, and a grey circle strike through indicator.  I am trying to access this badge - I've looked at the  `UIDragItem`, `UIDragPreview`, and `UIDragPreviewParamaters` docs, but I haven't had any luck to figure it out.  Even if I wasn't able to configure the badge itself, it would be great to at least just hide it and create my own.  If anyone can help out, that would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: any update on this?